# how to watch a sass file

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, sass

I just decided to start learning sass  but am still struggling a bit to run sass on my pc.I downloaded and installed it already as the pictures show:

[image]

[image]

The folder that I have the project is inside the htdocs folder in the xampp folder.
I typed C:\Users\Thulani>sass --watch C:\xampp\htdocs\ruby\lib\sass\style.scss:style.css on the command line but it only says sass is watching for changes.

[image]

How can I actually make changes in my style.scss and see those changes?

Here my html:

```
<html>
<head>
   <title> Import example of sass</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
</head>
<body>
   <h1>Simple Example</h1>
   <h3>Welcome to TutorialsPoint</h3>
</body>
</html>
```

Please help

Comment: Have you tried making changes to your style.scss? If you're running the `--watch` task, any changes made to the input will be compiled and output to the destination of your choosing. http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#using_sass

Comment: Yes.I try to changes something on the style.scss but nothing happens

Answer (score 1):

Use this command in the folder you want to watch.

```
sass -w src/assets
```

if you don't want map files use this

```
sass -w src/assets --sourcemap=none
```

Answer (score 0):

From what you have given I can only say that maybe you have made the mistake of not actually calling any class or id from your CSS file. It would have been nice if you could have uploaded that also, but I'll presume that you tried to style only the `<h1>` and `<h3>` elements. Since you're new I'll write you some very simple test code that should run.

Here is my HTML file:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en-GB">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="keywords" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1">

    <title>Test</title>

    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
 </head>
 <body>
    <div id="red">
       <h1>I am red !</h1>
     </div>
     <div id="blue">
       <h2>I am blue</h2>
     </div>
   </body>
```

My SCSS file:

```
    //@import "Filename";
// use import if you want to link two or more style sheets together (makes one big css file)

/* Colours used */
$red: red;
$blue: blue;

html, body{
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body {
    background-color: white;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
#red {
    color: $red;
}
#blue {
    color: $blue;
}
```

[SCSS to CSS conversion test pass](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bB8iF.png)